# Too many calls to Location or History APIs within a short timeframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

```js
 const OwnerPage = () => {
  const onOpen = useAgencyModal((state) => state.onOpen);
  const isOpen = useAgencyModal((state) => state.isOpen);
  const params = useParams();
  const [owner, setOwner] = useState<User | null>(null);
  const [agency, setAgency] = useState<any>([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`/api/owner/${params.ownerId}`, {
          method: "GET",
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        setAgency(data.agency);
        setOwner(data.owner);
        console.log("agency: " + data.agency);
        console.log("owner: " + data.owner);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error occurred while fetching data:", error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [params.ownerId]);
  const memoizedData = useMemo(() => {
    return { agency, owner };
  }, [agency, owner]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (memoizedData.agency !== null) {
      if (!isOpen) {
        onOpen();
      }
    } else {
      redirect(`/dashboard/owner/${params.ownerId}/dashboard`);
    }
  }, [memoizedData.agency, isOpen, onOpen, params.ownerId]);
  return null;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

(I want to comment but my reputation is less than 50,,)

I’m quite new to react but I’ve seen that warning several times. And it’s mostly because of infinite loop of useEffect for wrong dependencies.

I think the second useEffect causes the infinite loop. If memoizedData.agency is not null and isOpen is false, trigger onOpen. Then this causes state changes, re render, if memoizedData.agency, isOpen still meets the condition, re trigger onOpen, re render, …

Maybe it helps you to find the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is some context missing of what `useAgencyModal` is doing. Many lines in this code is also redundant.

1. `useMemo` is used for saving calculated values to prevent recalculation after every rendering cycle. Since all memorized values are already available without any additional operation you can remove those lines.

```
  const memoizedData = useMemo(() => {
    return { agency, owner };
  }, [agency, owner]);
```

2. States of `useState` with the same dependency in the `useEffect` dependency array often leads of a circular dependency which leads to this `Warning`. It helps to check where the state update triggers a useEffect which will trigger another state update.